# how do I quantize with dynamic range a fine-tuned mobilenet V2 model with new classification head

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I have been trying all day to quantize a fine-tuned model I have so I can deploy it to an edge TPU device and I have had 0 success.
I have tried quantizing the model with many permutations of the code on the tensorflow docs here : https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_integer_quant

when I pass a representational dataset to the converter, it always ends up having an error about how my data isn't formatted correctly, even when I tried loading it in the way that is shown on the examples, I have modified it to work in my own code as best as I can, but I don't know what it actually wants. I even tried preprocessing the image inputs even though I have preprocessing layers that do the operations themselves.

```
image_paths = list(glob('dataset/*/*.jpg'))

def load_and_preprocess_image(image_path):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [img_height, img_width])
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = image / 127.5  # Normalize the pixel values
    image -= 1
    return image

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(image_paths)
dataset = dataset.map(load_and_preprocess_image)

inputs = []
for x in dataset.take(4):
    inputs.append(x.numpy())

def representative_dataset_gen():
    for i in inputs:
        return i
    
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert() # Fails here

interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter(model_content=tflite_quant_model)
input_type = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['dtype']
print('input: ', input_type)
output_type = interpreter.get_output_details()[0]['dtype']
print('output: ', output_type)

import pathlib

tflite_models_dir = pathlib.Path("/tmp/fav-detector_tflite_models/")
tflite_models_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)

# Save the unquantized/float model:
tflite_model_file = tflite_models_dir/"fav-detector_tflite.tflite"
tflite_model_file.write_bytes(tflite_model)

# Save the quantized model:
tflite_model_file = tflite_models_dir/"fav-detector_tflite-quantized.tflite"
tflite_model_file.write_bytes(tflite_model)
```

I'd love to simply have some code that I can give the directory of my model, the directory of my images, and then let it quantize the model.